# Get object keys based on value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have a use case where I have an object of varying values, and I need to get all of these keys that have a specific value. For instance, here is a sample object:

```
myObject = {
    Person1: true,
    Person2: false,
    Person3: true,
    Person4: false
};
```

The key names will vary, but the valid values are true or false. I want to get an array of the names that have a value of true:

```
myArray2 = [
    'Person1',
    'Person3
];
```

I've been trying to use various lodash functions in combination such as _.key() and _.filter, but with no luck. How can I accomplish this? I'm open to pure JS or Lodash options.

**UPDATE:** I accepted mhodges' answer below as the accepted answer, although others gave me the same answer. Based on that, I came up with a Lodash version:

```
var myArray = _(myObject).keys().filter(function(e) {
    return myObject[e] === true;
}).value();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to use basic `.filter()` for this.

```
myObject = {
    Person1: true,
    Person2: false,
    Person3: true,
    Person4: false
};

var validKeys = Object.keys(myObject).filter(function (key) { 
    return myObject[key] === true; 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Lodash was tagged: With `pickBy` the values can be filtered (and the keys obtained with `_.keys` ):

```
var myArray2  = _.keys(_.pickBy(myObject));
```

```js
var myObject = {    Person1: true,    Person2: false,    Person3: true,    Person4: false  };
  
var myArray2  = _.keys(_.pickBy(myObject));

console.log(myArray2 );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh, nice. I missed _.pickBy(). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use Object.keys():

```
var object = {
    1: 'a',
    2: 'b',
    3: 'c'
};
console.log(Object.keys(object));
```

Alternative solution:

```
var keys = [];
for (var key in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        keys.push(key);
    }        
}    
console.log(keys);
```

Don't forget to check a `key` with the help of `hasOwnProperty()`, otherwise this approach may result in unwanted `keys` showing up in the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `Object.keys()` and `filter()`.

```js
var myObject = {
  Person1: true,
  Person2: false,
  Person3: true,
  Person4: false
};

var result = Object.keys(myObject).filter(function(e) {
  return myObject[e] === true;
})
console.log(result)
```

ES6 version with arrow function

```
var result = Object.keys(myObject).filter(e => myObject[e] === true)
```

Comment: Thanks Nenad. Unfortunately, I'm limited to ES5 at this point. What would ES5 syntax be?